# Error "Attempt to present xViewController on yViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy!" iOS8

Tags: ios

I have a view controller `yViewController`. I am adding it to the `rootViewController` as follows:

```
[self.window.rootViewController.view addSubView:yViewController.view]
```

I have a outlet `UIButton` on `yViewController` and on touch i am displaying a `xViewCOntroller` in a `UIPopOverController` using the following code to present it:

```
[popOver presentPopOverFromRect:button.frame inView:self.buttonContainerView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopOverArrowDirectionAny animated:NO]
```

It worked fine on iOS 7 however I am having the error on iOS 8:

```
Attempt to present xViewController on yViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Have you notified the view controller that is has moved to a parent one using will- and didMoveToParentViewController? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/willMoveToParentViewController:

Comment: No. you mean i should implement those methods in the viewController i am adding as a subview to the rootViewController? What do i need to notify?

Comment: You need to notify yViewController that it was added to a parent view controller

Comment: I did include those two methods in yViewController but the popOver still does not appear. Still throwing the same warning

Comment: no you have to call them from the parent controller

Comment: I did the following:[self.window.rootviewController addViewController:yViewController]; [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:yViewController.view]; [yViewController didMoveToParentController] still no progress :(